# What's the meaning of the caret sign ^ in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

Given i have a variable in fortran programming declared as a = 50 , b = 40
what is the result of variable c = a ^ 2? does this sign ^ represent modulo?

Comment: `c=a^2` isn't Fortran.

Comment: Why do you think this has a meaning?  Have you seen source code with it, or does your compiler accept it?  Of course, it my appear in a character context `print *, "c=a^2"`.

Comment: If caret appears where it is invalid, it likely means forgetfulness about which language us in use.  It does have various meanings in other programming languages.

Comment: `^` is sometimes used as exponent but in most languages (including fortran) you'd use `**`

Answer (score 5):

**No**, `^` is not an operator in fortran.